# Get single unique row from duplicate data with multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the unique data from multiple tables with the highest id
Refer below data

Users Table

```
    id  firstname_english   
------  --------------------
     2  Lama                
     4  Akram               
     6  Ammar               
     8  Basil               
    10  Sami                
    12  Hasan               
    14  Adnan               
    16  Mamoon              
    18  Sulaiman            
    20  Wasfi               
    22  Mervat
```

Users form status with their id

```
   id  users_id  status_id  
------  -----------  -----------
     3            2           10
   368            4           10
     5            4           10
   402            6            9
     7            6           10
     9            8           10
    11           10           10
   223           10           10
    13           12           10
  3253           14            2
    15           14           10
    17           16           10
  1488           16            9
   231           16           10
    19           18           10
    22           20           10
   750           20            9
   232           22           10
    24           22           10
  2935           22            9
   297           22           10
```

The Result I need

```
id  firstname_english          status_id       form_id 
------  --------------------   --------------------
     2  Lama                      10             3
     4  Akram                     10             368
     6  Ammar                     9               402
     8  Basil                     10               8
    10  Sami                     10              223
    12  Hasan                     10              12
 ........and so on
```

I need to display the highest data from the table 2 with the matching id of table 1

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Someone with your reputation should now how to tag questions.

Comment: Considering the OP states "MySQL" in the title, this *suggests* they want a MySQL Solution, but why *did* you tag 4 completely RDBMS..? That just adds multiple layers of confusion. If you don't know what RDBMS you're using, how are a bunch of strangers on the internet supposed to know?

Comment: What is the query you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ use `row_number()` window function:

```
select 
  u.id, u.firstname_english,
  f.status_id, f.id form_id      
from users u inner join (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by users_id order by id desc) rn
  from users_form 
) f on f.users_id = u.id
where f.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/muSvWT5Nf3tSiLkZHLy1iT/0).
For previous versions of MySql:

```
select 
  u.id, u.firstname_english,
  f.status_id, f.id form_id      
from users u inner join (
  select uf.* from users_form uf
  where not exists (
    select 1 from users_form
    where users_id = uf.users_id and id > uf.id
  ) 
) f on f.users_id = u.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/muSvWT5Nf3tSiLkZHLy1iT/2).

Results:

```
| id  | firstname_english | status_id | form_id |
| --- | ----------------- | --------- | ------- |
| 2   | Lama              | 10        | 3       |
| 4   | Akram             | 10        | 368     |
| 6   | Ammar             | 9         | 402     |
| 8   | Basil             | 10        | 9       |
| 10  | Sami              | 10        | 223     |
| 12  | Hasan             | 10        | 13      |
| 14  | Adnan             | 2         | 3253    |
| 16  | Mamoon            | 9         | 1488    |
| 18  | Sulaiman          | 10        | 19      |
| 20  | Wasfi             | 9         | 750     |
| 22  | Mervat            | 9         | 2935    |
```

Comment: that's work thanks for providing the older version too :)